# Removing log in/sign up account in my shop

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart

I have noticed that many customers in my online store get to checkout and then are asked to sign in/create an account. They then leave the website. How can I make it easier for them? Is it possible to remove the sign in/register option so they can go straight to the payment gateway?

I am using magento version 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Darren,Magento has **an  inbuilt feature** by which ***customer can checkout  with out login./register by enabled setting*** .

**Customer can easy checkout as guest**.Just goto ***admin Section>System>Configuration>Sales>Checkout*** and make `Allow Guest Checkout`=`Yes`
[image]

Comment: Hi Amit.Thanks for that. I have already guest checkout enabled, but it seems that some customers think this is still too longdrawn and they abandon the basket.I am having my website redesigned and the webdesigner suggested that we remove the sign up/guest function all together and just let them go to the payment gateway. is that possible?

Comment: remove sign up/log that can be an idea but what about rest og steps billing,shipping,shiping method,review?

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that the Magento checkout is no more drawn out than any other that requires a shipping address and payment method. Studies have shown that the Magento checkout is not any worse than so-called 1-page checkouts (although you should make sure you have 1-page checkout enabled in Magento; it's not quite the same as some extensions can provide, but if you're not using it, you should. Under Sales > Checkout > Checkout Options.)

We actually remove the Guest Checkout option as the only difference is the presence of a password field. Instead, we re-label the headings on the top of the checkout "New Customer?" and "Existing Customer?" In this way, it's quick and easy for a customer to say, "I'm a new customer," and click the "Continue" button.

If you're having huge abandonments in the checkout page specifically, work at creating a Google Analytics funnel to track where in the checkout process people are bailing. It might not be the length of the form (do you have specifics to back this up?). It might be your shipping rates or lack of certain payment methods.

You should also test your checkout to make sure 1.7.x isn't throwing some warnings or errors relating to security flaws, etc.

As for your web designer: if s/he does not have proven experience operating e-commerce stores, take their advice with a grain of salt. Amit is correct, you still have to obtain shipping address, shipping method and payment method.

Sorry for a long post, but one more thing. If you're selling expensive items, customers will appreciate the care with which you're attending their most private information. Use the checkout page to promote your security efforts, your guarantee, etc. But don't overload it with messaging. Keep it simple and clean.

The one thing I would like to have seen in Magento 1.x (which is different in M2) is the ability to create a clean checkout without top navigation and other "clutter." It can be done, but it's not a native setting.

Good luck!